# How do I pass an array by reference to a class?

Tags: c++

This is from main:

```
test.Begin(static_cast<Start::Person>(player[NUM_PLAYERS]), NUM_PLAYERS);
```

"static_cast" is underlined in red, and when I mouse over it says:

Error: no suitable conversion function from "Start::Person" to "Start::Person *" exists

This is from start.h:

```
void Begin (Person *, int);
```

This is from start.cpp

```
void Start::Begin (Person *player[4], int NUM_PLAYERS)
```

"Begin" from start.cpp is underlined in red, and when I mouse over it, the error says:

Error: declaration is incompatible with "void Start::Begin(Start::Person *, int)"

followed by the location of the line I already showed for start.h

Comment: you just need to pass an array by reference right? why static cast ? Use usual methods `&` , or either I'm not getting your question.

Comment: Your start.h and start.cpp are too different. One pointer != 4 pointers. Fix this first before thinking about main (Arrays are not passed with an index, especially not with an out-of-range index). I recommend reading a good C++ book before continuing.

Answer (score 1):

```
// assunimg 'player' is an array
test.Begin(player, NUM_PLAYERS); // no cast
```

start.h:

```
void Begin (Person [], int);
```

start.c:

```
void Start::Begin (Person player[], int NUM_PLAYERS)
```

Answer (score 0):

The second error is because your definition of `Begin` does not match your declaration for `Begin`. Your declaration is passing a `Person*` whereas your definition is accepting an array 4 of `Person`. You can fix this by changing your definition (in your .cpp file) to:

```
void Start::Begin(Start::Person* player, int);
```

Which will then match your definition. You can call this with the following:

```
Start::Person players[10] = {};
// Assume 's' is an object of type Start
s.Begin(players, 10);
```

This requires you to pass an index to a `Person` and then the number of elements. You can make this *better* by matching your declaration of `Begin` to your definition:

```
void Begin(Start::Person players[4]);
```

Now `Begin` will only accept an array of 4 `Person`, which you can call with the following:

```
Start::Person players[4] = {};
// Assume 's' is an object of type Start
s.Begin(players);
```

This will pass a COPY of the array into `Begin`. You can further improve this with the following declaration/definition:

```
template <size_t size>
void Begin(const Person (&players)[size]);
```

This will pass a const reference to an array of any size of `Person`; that is a direct reference (so no copies are made) which is unmodifiable, which you can call with any of the following:

```
Start::Person oldPlayers[6] = {};
Start::Person newPlayers[15] = {};
Start::Person mvps[3] = {};
s.Begin(oldPlayers);
s.Begin(newPlayers);
s.Begin(mvps);
```

Comment: The array won´t ever get copied